# How to make multiple monitors show same screen but with different resolutions

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors

Is it possible to have 2 or more monitors show the same screen, for example the same desktop but with different resolutions. Like the clone option in Nvidia or the mirror option using the Display settings in Ubuntu but instead of showing the same output with the same resolution, they both show the same output using a resolution that is native for each monitor connected (independent resolution sizes).

In my case if I have a netbook that has max resolution of 1360x768 and a TV that has 1280x1024, the would both show the same desktop but each with their own resolution that is compatible for each device. This would help in trying to find a resolution that works on both monitors and in cases like a mini netbook and a huge TV it would solve issues like having max 800x600 in one monitor and min 1024x768 in the other. In the case I tested I was using an HDMI cable but this question also involves VGA and any other connection.

I have 3 tests scenarios for this:

Scenario 1 - Laptop HP DV6000 (Intel Integrated Video) with 1360x760 connected to a Samsung LED 42 TV that has 1280x900.

Scenario 2 - Laptop EEE with 1024x600 (Intel Integrated Video) connected to Sony LCD TV that supports 1280x900.

Scenario 3 - Intel Desktop with Nvidia 440 GT with HDMI connected to Soneview 32' TV that supports 1920x1080 and VGA connected to an Epson Video Beam that supports 1280x1024 max.

In this 3 scenarios I need to be able to show the same desktop and same views but on different resolutions for each output device.

UPDATE: Tested with Xubuntu and the way it handles multiple monitors is precisely what I am asking. The ability to handle the resolution of different monitors showing the same thing.

Comment: I've done this plenty of times in the past, what graphics card do you have? In 11.04, I had no problems using the Display preferences screen to use HDMI out and VGA out simultaneously from my old Intel laptop and don't really have problems with my MBP running FGLRX.

Comment: I have added the test systems I am using.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible, as it would require rendering the display twice independently but simultaneously at two different resolutions (and thus require that X be resolution independent).  You could probably render the desktop as a GL texture and scale it to the different resolutions but I'm not aware of any project to do that currently.

Comment: @fader - Hi buddy, can you check if it is possible now. If not, then put that as an answer so I can accept it for the time being. Am really hoping there is a way since it can help in many cases.